# how to enforce hard limit 16MB on document size in rethinkdb

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, nosql

As rethinkdb suggest to keep the document size 16MB max for the performance reason. In my nodejs rest api app user can insert data using api. I cannot control how much data would be for an user. each user has individual document in a users table. based on rethinkdb advise trying to put a limit on the document max 16MB. so that any user document cannot grow beyond that limit.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to enforce limits on document size inside of RethinkDB right now.  You'd have to add code to whatever is serving the REST endpoint to do that check.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, thats how we are doing it now